# JQuery: How to callback each loop after completion of ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How to callback each loop after completion of ajax call.

Please find my code as follows.

**Story:**

Let us assume I have 3 values X,Y,Z. Firstly, I am taking X value, sending to django views and their using **requests** module for getting some info and pushing to the div class **push_new_info_here**, in the next Iteration I have to take Y value. How to do ? please note: Previous ajax call should be succeeded .

Final word: I am collecting all the info of (X,Y,Z), then merging using python and pushing to the div class **push_new_info_here**

```
window.onload = function() {

  $.each(["X","Y","Z"], function( index, value ) {

      $.post('/find/'+value+'/',{},function(data){
          $('.push_new_info_here').empty();
          $('.push_new_info_here').html(data);
      });

  });

};
```

Comment: so u want to wait for the successful return of the `$.post` call before continuing to the next value, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this - use .append if you want to see the data or change the timeout to something long enough for the user to see:

```
var arr = ["X","Y","Z"],cnt=0;

function postIt() {
  if (cnt >= arr.length) return; // stop
  $.post('/find/'+arr[cnt]+'/',{},function(data){
      $('.push_new_info_here').empty().html(data); // or .append
      cnt++; 
      postIt(); // or setTimeout(postIt,3000); // give server a breather
  });
}


$(function() {
  postIt();
});
```

Comment: No worries, just a couple small touchups.

Comment: @mplungjan: Thanks man..perfect !! Unfortunately i don't have enough points to either vote-up (nor) accept the answer.
Any one, could you please accept this answer. It would be highly appreciable..

Comment: @mplungjan: Earlier, click doesn't work, it says you don't have enough reputation..may be its a bug

Answer (score 1):

try wrapping the call in a function, then recursing through the array using the AJAX .done method.  For example

```
window.onload = function() {
  recursiveAjax(["X","Y","Z"])
};

function recursiveAjax(values){
  //basic error testing
  if (typeof values == "undefined" || values.length == 0) return false
  var value = values.pop();
  $.post('/find/'+value+'/',{},function(data){
    $('.push_new_info_here').empty();
    $('.push_new_info_here').html(data);
    recursiveAjax(values)
  });
}'
```

EDIT:
To avoid destroying the array we can send a cloned copy through to the function. For example:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var tempArray = ["X","Y","Z"]
  recursiveAjax(tempArray.slice())
};
```

Comment: That will destroy the array but I like the simpler way of passing the array

Comment: Indeed. We could clone it and send the clone through to maintain the array's integrity, though I don't know why.  All depends on whether we need the array around after the call.